# Drop row based on time

Tags: pandas, time, row

I want to know how to drop row based on time column. My dataframe:

```
df
ID   Time
ID1 9:00:00
ID2 10:00:00
ID3 11:00:00
ID4 12:00:00
ID5 13:00:00
ID6 14:00:00
ID7 15:00:00
ID8 16:00:00
ID9 17:00:00
```

I want to eliminate row below than 11:00:00 and above 15:00:00, so expected a result:

```
Result
ID   Time
ID3 11:00:00
ID4 12:00:00
ID5 13:00:00
ID6 14:00:00
ID7 15:00:00
```

I use this code but nothing happens.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
index_list= df.Time[(df.Time < "09:00:00") & (df.Time > "17:00:00")].index.tolist()
df.drop(df.index[index_list] , inplace = True)
df
```

Comment: what is `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: @jezrael-`time object` and `ìd  object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert values to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and filter by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
print (df.dtypes)
ID               object
Time    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object

df = df[df['Time'].between('11:00:00','15:00:00')]
print (df)
    ID     Time
2  ID3 11:00:00
3  ID4 12:00:00
4  ID5 13:00:00
5  ID6 14:00:00
6  ID7 15:00:00
```

Comment: How would you do this with a timestamp column without creating a new column?

Comment: @Datanovice  - solution is create `DatetimeIndex` and filter by [`Series.between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between_time.html)

Comment: Ah that's what I've been doing but thought I may be wrong, thanks Joži!

Comment: @Datanovice - :) Ya, here is simplier use timedeltas, but it is also solution :) Nice Sunday :)