# Drop row using time interval or threshold in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner in python
I have a `dataframe` which appears every second. My data looks like this

```
    Time    Id
0   9:00:00 A
1   9:00:30 B
2   9:00:50 C
3   9:01:03 D
4   9:01:25 E
5   9:02:04 F
```

Based on this post [Drop row based on time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559498/drop-row-based-on-time), I want to drop row by time interval or the threshold (1 minute). However, I have huge row data and I could not use the URL answer. 
My expected result looks like this.

```
    Time    Id
0   9:00:00 A
1   9:01:03 D
2   9:02:04 F
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

- [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) - Convert argument to timedelta.
- [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) -A Grouper allows the user to specify a groupby instruction for a target object.
- [`.GroupBy.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) - Compute first of group values.
- [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) - Reset the index, or a level of it.

  Need parameter `as_index=False` in [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) or [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for convert index to columns:

**Ex.**

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1 min', key='Time'))['Time','Id'].first().reset_index(drop=True)
print(df1)
```

OR

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
df1 = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1 min', key='Time')],as_index=False)['Time','Id'].first()
print(df1)
```

**O/P:**

```
      Time Id
0 09:00:00  A
1 09:01:03  D
2 09:02:04  F
```

Comment: I got an error message `Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'`

Comment: thank you for your answer, would you mind to see my update question. is it possible if another column data and the name of the column still exist?

Comment: @Arief Updated answer, try now.

Comment: waww thank you, you are awesome. Is there a way to keep other columns instead of writing the column name? ex. `['Time','Id']`

Comment: @Arief Groupby always Splitting the data into groups based on some criteria, In your case, Groupby create groups by 1 min like `9:00, 9:01` and `9:02`, if you try to get first group value without writing the column `['Time','Id']`, it will not give the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest would be using resample,

```
df.resample('1T')
```